# Question about the UNION operator and its implicit data type conversions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a limit to the number of UNION operators to combine query results?

I have an odd situation where I have a table called TransmittalSheet TS that have a double (1 to Many) relationships with each of the 2 tables: (DocumentInfo and EquipmentJobPlan tables), they both have almost the same exact column names and data types. 
Each primary key (TransmittalID)  that’s coming from the parent table TS above, have two corresponding foreign keys in each of the children tables above. FK pair columns are called: (Docs_Implementing, Docs_Obsolescing) and (JobPlan_TS_Implementing and JobPlan_TS_Obsolescing).

I need to query if each Transmittal have any documents or equipmentJobPlans are associated with it (either Imp or Obs for each table association), so I believe I need to have 3 UNION operators like this:

```
Select A, B, C , ‘Imp Doc’ as DocType
From DocumentInfo As Di INNER JOIN TransmittalSheet TS 
ON Di.DocumentTransmittal_IMP = TS.TransmittalID
Where TransmittalNumber = ‘TS- 0001’
Union
Select A, B, C , ‘Obs Doc’ as DocType
From DocumentInfo As Di INNER JOIN TransmittalSheet TS
ON Di.DocumentTransmittal_OBS = TS.TransmittalID
Where TransmittalNumber = ‘TS- 0001’
Union
Select A, B, C , ‘Imp JP’ as DocType
From EquipmentJobPlan As EQ  INNER JOIN TransmittalSheet TS
ON EQ.JobPlanTransmittal_IMP = TS.TransmittalID
Where TransmittalNumber = ‘TS- 0001’
Union
Select A, B, C , ‘Obs JP’ as DocType
From EquipmentJobPlan As EQ  INNER JOIN TransmittalSheet TS
ON EQ.JobPlanTransmittal_OBS = TS.TransmittalID
Where TransmittalNumber = ‘TS- 0001’
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Using SQL Server 2008R2.

Also, it seems that Union is doing some data conversion for column C for example: both columns are capturing document versions. It has a data type of varchar(75) in the DocumentInfo table, but it has a smallDateTime in the JobPlan table, , should I have an explicit conversion in place or the implicit Coversion that the Union is doing will be OK? Thanks

Comment: Why is column C only a date/time type in one table?

Comment: They used to record the JobPlan document versions (column C) by the date that it was entered and when it versions up then they record the updated date as the current version for the same doc number, but the other regular document versions in the DocInfo table are entered as 1.1 or 1.2, 1.3... when it versions up. So when I have the Union now for this report, I wasn't sure how its handled. Thanks

Comment: If I’m understanding the Data Types Precedence correctly, I expected the lowest precedence data type of (Varchar) to be converted to the highest (Smalldatetime) data type implicitly without specifying the CAST or Convert, correct? 
But I’m still getting the error that the conversion failed (error Msg. 295).

Comment: Ok, so I added the CAST and it seems my query is running successfully, I thought that SQL should of done it internally:

.
.
.
    Union
    Select A, B, CAST(C as Char)
    From EquipmentJobPlan As EQ  INNER JOIN TransmittalSheet TS
    ON EQ.JobPlanTransmittal_OBS = TS.TransmittalID
    Where TransmittalNumber = ‘TS- 0001’

Comment: Sure, it can follow the rules of data type precedence, but if the varchar column contains any value that *can't* be converted to SMALLDATETIME, boom. And because you're using UNION instead of UNION ALL, you may be more likely to hit invalid values because the additional DISTINCT SORT operations this (usually) adds.

Comment: What values that can’t be converted to smalldatetime as it wasn’t clear for me from BOL? Since the Varchar column (DocumentVersion) contains values that have numbers like 1.1, 2.0, 0.3, or dates like 11/11/2010 or some versions have both), that’s why I’m assuming the Varchar was chosen, unlike the other column (JobPlanVersion), which stores only date versions as it’s a SMALLDATETIME.
I chose UNION as users don’t need to see the duplicated values. I can add the UNION ALL and add other columns to the SELECT statement to make the row unique in case of duplication documents appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, you can certainly simplify your query, for example (I've added [schema prefixes, which you should always use](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)):

```
Select A, B, C
  From dbo.DocumentInfo As Di INNER JOIN dbo.TransmittalSheet TS 
  ON TS.TransmittalID IN (Di.DocumentTransmittal_IMP, Di.DocumentTransmittal_OBS)
  Where TransmittalNumber = 'TS- 0001'
UNION
Select A, B, C
  From dbo.EquipmentJobPlan As EQ dbo.INNER JOIN TransmittalSheet TS
  ON TS.TransmittalID IN (EQ.JobPlanTransmittal_IMP, EQ.JobPlanTransmittal_OBS)
  Where TransmittalNumber = 'TS- 0001';
```

Or perhaps even:

```
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM dbo.TransmittalSheet TS
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DocumentInfo As Di 
  ON TS.TransmittalID IN (Di.DocumentTransmittal_IMP, Di.DocumentTransmittal_OBS)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EquipmentJobPlan As EQ
  ON TS.TransmittalID IN (EQ.JobPlanTransmittal_IMP, EQ.JobPlanTransmittal_OBS)
WHERE TS.TransmittalNumber = 'TS- 0001' 
AND COALESCE(Di.KeyColumn, EQ.KeyColumn) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A, B, C;
```

(I don't know if the `GROUP BY` is necessary, because I don't know if you are using `UNION` on purpose for the intention of removing duplicates. Though I do recommend putting table aliases on *all* column references, so readers have a clue which columns come from which tables. You may need to use `COALESCE` here and choose which table takes precedence for any of the output columns if `A`, `B` or `C` don't come from `TransmittalSheet`.)

Now, you say that when you use a `UNION` you get a conversion error, because in one of the tables column C is a `varchar` and in another it is a `smalldatetime`. Your options are:

1. To *fix* that. If you are considering those columns to be the same and compatible, they should be of the same data type and contain like data. Which means changing the data type after you remove any data that can't be directly converted to `smalldatetime`.
2. If the `varchar` column needs to have different data that is not compatible with `smalldatetime`, then perhaps it is best to present that as a different output column in your `UNION` query.
3. After that, you can apply an explicit cast on the `smalldatetime` type so that it can be converted to `varchar`, instead of the way SQL Server will do it (which is to try to convert the string to a date). If you want to only present valid `smalldatetime` data, then you can `CAST` the other way, but use a `CASE` expression so that the conversion is only attempted on valid data. The implicit conversion *can* follow the rules of data type precedence, but if the `varchar` column contains any value that **can't** be converted to `smalldatetime`, it fails with Msg 295, as you've discovered. This can happen even if those rows don't appear in the output - the conversion can occur before the rows are filtered out (I've written about this [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93425/1186), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5313/1186), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305930/61305) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21316088/61305) and it was reported as a bug on Connect (RIP). And because you're using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, you may be more likely to hit invalid values because the additional `DISTINCT SORT` operations this (usually) adds, which can change the way SQL Server will optimize the overall plan.

So, if you can't benefit from the re-writes above (or if they produce different results for some reason), and you can't do 1. or 2., then I would re-write the `UNION` version either like this:

```
-- against the table where C is smalldatetime:
SELECT A, B, CONVERT(CHAR(10), C, 120)
FROM ...

-- or against the table where C is varchar:
SELECT A, B, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CASE WHEN ISDATE(C) = 1 THEN C END)
FROM ...
```

A more localized example you can play with:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(A INT, B INT, C VARCHAR(75));
CREATE TABLE dbo.bar(A INT, B INT, C SMALLDATETIME);    
INSERT dbo.foo(A,B,C) VALUES(1,2,'three'),(2,4,'20150101');
INSERT dbo.bar(A,B,C) VALUES(1,2,'20050101'),(2,4,'20050101');
GO

-- these both work of course:
SELECT A,B,C FROM dbo.foo WHERE ISDATE(C) = 1;
SELECT A,B,CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,C) FROM dbo.foo WHERE ISDATE(C) = 1;
GO

-- fails:
SELECT A,B,C FROM dbo.foo
UNION
SELECT A,B,C FROM dbo.bar;
GO

-- succeeds, but may not always:
SELECT A,B,C FROM dbo.foo WHERE ISDATE(C) = 1
UNION 
SELECT A,B,C FROM dbo.bar;
GO

-- succeeds:
SELECT A, B, C = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CASE WHEN ISDATE(C) = 1 THEN C END)
FROM dbo.foo
UNION 
SELECT A, B, C FROM dbo.bar;

-- succeeds:
SELECT A, B, C FROM dbo.foo
UNION 
SELECT A, B, C = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), C, 120) FROM dbo.bar;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.foo, dbo.bar;
```

Finally, [please don't `CAST( AS Char)` with no length, or any other variable type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: I didn't add the schema prefixes in my question above for shortness You are right as I should kick this habit out too, thanks for the reminder. 
I really liked how you simplified it in both queries above, I don’t know why I didn't think about the IN sub-query in the references!
It seems that I can’t do your suggestion in number 1., and I wasn't sure what you meant by “…present that as a different output column in your UNION query ” in number 2., so I ran your query that has the single UNION with IN subquery and it seems giving me the data that I need, will test with different TSnumbers too.

Comment: Just curious how I can add an output column in the Select statement that just displays the DocType to differentiate if its (Implementing or Obsolescing like you have it in subquery) depending if it’s coming from the Document table or the JobPlan table,  that’s why I had 4 queries originally with 3 UNIONs:

    Select A, B, C , D  
     From dbo.DocumentInfo As Di INNER JOIN dbo.TransmittalSheet   TS 
      ON TS.TransmittalID IN (Di.DocumentTransmittal_IMP AS IMP???,   Di.DocumentTransmittal_OBS AS Obs????)
      Where TransmittalNumber = 'TS- 0001'
    UNION
......

Comment: Please see how I added the fourth column in my original code, to see if I can accomplish something like that in your UNION query code above. Thanks.